# Wireless keyboard/mouse causes internet connection to fail

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I have a Windows 10 laptop which accesses the internet via a BT wireless router. When I plug in a wireless keyboard and mouse (via a 2.4GHz USB key) I lose the ability to access web pages. When I unplug said key I regain internet access immediately, then lose it again if I plug the key back in.

What is happening? How might I resolve this issue?

Comment: As a (not very good) workaround I am unplugging the bluetooth receiver every time I visit a web page! :-/

Comment: As per comments below, I eventually decided to simply switch to wired mouse and keyboard. Inexpensive and problem solved! :-)

Comment: This post has reached 2500 views. A lot of Bluetooth trouble our there in the world!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Internet connection is via WiFi, then interference is certainly possible.

To communicate between your devices, Bluetooth sends signals over a 2.4GHz radio frequency. This becomes problematic when other nearby devices are also using that frequency. Wi-Fi is perhaps the biggest and most problematic example, as are other Bluetooth receivers and devices, which can interfere with one another.

How to mitigate Frequency Interference :

1. Remove All Barriers: Certain building materials can get in the way of weaker signals like Bluetooth. Metal, bulletproof glass, concrete and plaster are particularly bad, and marble, plaster and brick aren’t great.
2. Change Router Channel: Specifically, a different channel than the one your Bluetooth devices are using to communicate.
3. Connect to a 5 GHz wireless network (if possible).
4. Move your computer and Wi-Fi router closer to each other, or use wired connection.

Comment: What straightforward, sensible advice @harrymc. Many thanks. I will look into options (2) and (3) as I can't really do anything about (1) and (4).

Comment: The conclusion I came to was that the easiest thing was to switch to an old-fashioned wired Microsoft keyboard and HP mouse!